# Расстановка знаков между числами

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Даны N чисел. Нужно расставить + и * между ними и получить максимум.

К примеру - 1,2,3,1,2,3

Ответ - 1+2*3*1*2*3 = 37

Есть ли у Вас идеи, может алгоритмы какие-либо, или статьи с объяснением решения, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: если первое число 1, то поставить +, а между остальными  *, если не нулевые

Comment: Числа всегда положительные?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, тоже думал об этом, но мне кажется что тут не всё так просто. А если 1 стоит в середине где-нибудь, например 2,1,1,1,2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, положительные

Comment: Какие ограничения на количество чисел? Кстати, предельное значение тоже важно - в плане реализации уже: нужна ли длинная арифметика или вписываемся в стандартные типы...

Comment: @Harry, от 0 до 109

Comment: В смысле, 10^9? Миллиард чисел? 8-0 Никакая длинная арифметика не спасет...

Comment: @Harry, нет, в смысле сами числа могут быть в диапазоне от 0 до 109, а их количество 2<=n<=200000

Comment: Нереально. Предельное значение - миллиард в степени 200000 - памяти не очень-то хватит на числа с почти двумя миллионами знаков. О времени просто молчу. О переборе нужно забыть сразу, при таком количестве предел - O(n*log n), даже O(n^2) - уже не просчитываемо.

Comment: @Harry, да мне бы для начала понять принцип работы для 10 чисел

Comment: Для 10 - простой перебор. До 20 - еще он. Дальше - ну, *ощущение* динамического программирования, но что-то не соображу навскидку, как. Еще вариант - ветвление с отсечениями.

Comment: @Harry Да, с помощью ДП можно за квадарат или около того. F[i] = максимальная сумма (в рамках разумного чтобы не вычислять) собранная на первых i элементах. Пересчёт просто цикл куда группу "подвешивать".   Если добавить эвристики типа "если оба числа не меньше 2 то*, если 1 с краю то +", потом просто добавив отсечение "если ответ очень большой то остальное умножить" то числа в вычислениях не превысят 64 бита. Квадрат - медленно, но должно успеть с учётом эвристик.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете использовать рекурсию и сделать это перебором вариантов. Не самая красивая реализация в плане производительности, но в плане читаемости очень даже.

Получится дерево переборов. В листах дерева (когда будет получена полная подстановка знаков) вычисляете выражение и сравниваете с максимумом.

Код будет что-то наподобие такого:

```
using namespace std;

vector<char> signs = { '+', '-', '*', '%', '/' };
int maxValue = 0;
vector<char> combin;

int calculateExpression(const vector<int> &, const vector<char> &);

void recursiveFunction(const vector<int> & values, vector<char> & combination, size_t level) 
{
  if(level == combination.size()) // Комбинация сформирована, можно вычислять.
  {
    int value = calculateExpression(values, combination);
    if(value > maxValue) {
      combin = combination;
      maxValue = value;
    }
    return;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < signs.size(); i++) {
    combination[level] = signs[i];
    recursiveFunction(values, combination, level + 1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> digits { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  vector<char> combinations(digits.size() - 1);

  recursiveFunction(digits, combinations, 0);

  cout << "Максимальное значение: " << maxValue << endl;
  cout << "Комбинация знаков: ";
  for(int i = 0; i < combin.size(); ++i) {
    cout << digits[i] << " " << combin[i] << " " << digits[i + 1] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Функцию calculateExpression напишите сами. И вектора также исправите на обычные массивы, если нужно.

Что касается вычисления выражения, то здесь вам в помощь обратная польская запись. Реализуется просто, статей предостаточно.

Comment: Необязательно рекурсию здесь делать, если изначально поставить все знаки как `+`, то дальше можно просто перебирать маски. Для N чисел будет N-1 позиций куда можно поставить `*`, это можно представить как число из N-1 бит, и получим 2^(N-1) комбинаций, которые нужно проверить. Но мне кажется что здесь нужно идти от подпоследовательностей единиц в последовательности. Только единицы мешают поставить везде знаки умножения

Comment: Да, необязательно. Как уже сказал, МОЖНО использовать рекурсию.
Перебор циклами, к сожалению, не сделаешь, если не знаешь заранее, сколько можно вариантов перебрать. Данное же решение обладает вполне неплохой гибкостью.

Comment: Перебор - ну, до 20 чисел запросто, до 30 - уже будет долговато :(

Comment: Нашёл статью, может будет интересно Вам - [ссылка](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%C7%E0%E4%E0%F7%E0_%EE_%F0%E0%F1%F1%F2%E0%ED%EE%E2%EA%E5_%E7%ED%E0%EA%EE%E2_%E2_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%E8)